# Change html structure of all img tags in Wordpress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, function, preg-replace

I have a Wordpress blog and am trying to implement the [foresight.js](https://github.com/adamdbradley/foresight.js) image script. In short, I need to target all post images, swap out the `src, width, & height` attributes with `data-src, data-width, & data-height` attributes. I then need to duplicate the image line and wrap it in `<noscript>` tags. This is the structure I'm trying to have Wordpress generate/create:

```
<img data-src="wordpress/image/url/pic.jpg" data-width="{get width of image with PHP & pass-in that value here} data-height="{get height of image with PHP and pass-in that value here}" class="fs-img">
<noscript>
    <img src="wordpress/image/url/pic.jpg">
</noscript>
```

[More info can be found at foresight.js' website](http://www.cdnconnect.com/docs/foresightjs/img-element).

I have searched the Wordpress codex and the best possible route I can find are to use filters (ie. *'get_image_tag'* & *'image_tag'*) for modifying the html that Wordpress outputs for each image. I'm thinking that one of these options should work, or that I can do some pattern matching with regex *(I know, not ideal)*, throw in a `preg_replace` and then inject this back into `the_content` filter.

I have tried some of these options but cannot get any to work. Could someone please offer some help?

#### 'get_image_tag' attempt:

*Found this particular one on the web, but it would need modified to fit my logic (see above structure)...can't make sense of what the `preg_replace` array is doing on my own.*

```
<?php function image_tag($html, $id, $alt, $title) {
    return preg_replace(array(
        '/'.str_replace('//','\/\/',get_bloginfo('url')).'/i',
        '/\s+width="\d+"/i',
        '/\s+height="\d+"/i',
        '/alt=""/i'
    ),
    array(
        '',
        '',
        '',
        alt='"' . $title . '"'
    ),
    $html);
}
add_filter('get_image_tag', 'image_tag', 0, 4);
?>
```

#### Another 'get_image_tag' attempt:

```
<?php function get_image_tag($id, $alt, $title, $align, $size='full') {
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($img_src);
    $hwstring = image_hwstring($width, $height);

    $class = 'align' . esc_attr($align) . ' size-' . esc_attr($size) . ' wp-image-' . $id;
    $class = apply_filters('get_image_tag_class', $class, $id, $align, $size);

    $html = '<img src="' . esc_attr($img_src) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($alt) . '" title="' . esc_attr($title).'" data-width="' . $width . '" data-height="' . $height . '" class="' . $class . ' fs-img" />';
    $html = apply_filters( 'get_image_tag', $html, $id, $alt, $title, $align, $size);

    return $html;
}
?>
```

#### Pattern-matching attempt:

Tried creating my own regex on this one, but not sure if it's correct.

```
<?php function restructure_imgs($content) {
    global $post;
    $pattern = "/<img(.*?)src=('|\")(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)(|\")(.*?)>/i";

    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($2$3.$4$5);
    $hwstring = image_hwstring($width, $height);

    $replacement = '<img$1data-src=$2$3.$4$5 title="'.$post->post_title.'" data-width="'.$width.'" data-height="'.$height.'" class="fs-img"$6>';
    $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'restructure_imgs');
?>
```

Unfortunately can't get any of these examples to work. Any help or sharing your pre-written scripts/functions would be much appreciated! Thanks for helping a student learn!!

Comment: You shouldn't parse HTML with Regex, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is *before* the page rendering and i think is not impossible in wordpress, however you can do the same *after* the page was rendered with javascript.
I tried to do that with jQuery and ti seems to work:

```
<!-- Example image -->
<img src="http://fotografia.deagostinipassion.com/resources/photos/2/2n/ilCielo.JPG" width="200px" height="300px">

<!-- Import jquery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("img").wrap(function() {

        $(this).wrap(function() {

            var newimg = '<img data-src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" data-width="' + $(this).attr('width') + '" data-height="' + $(this).attr('height') + '" class="fs-img">';
            return newimg;  

        });

        return '<noscript>';
    });

});

</script>
```

If you need more help, ask me.